# Copying and Pasting in Excel 2013

Tags: copy-paste

How do I copy cell H47 of Sheet 2 to Sheet 500 then paste it to Sheet 1 where A2 for Sheet2 H47; A3 for Sheet3 H47;  A4 for Sheet4 H47; A5 for Sheet5 H47....  A500 for Sheet500 H47

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, in VBA, you could do:

`Sub CopyToManySheets

Dim copyRng as Range 

Set copyRng = Range ("Sheet2!$H$47") 

copyRng.select

Selection.copy 

Dim index as integer 

For index = 1 to 500 

    If Not (IsError (Range ("Sheet" & index & "!A" & index))) Then 

        Range ("Sheet" & index & "!A" & index).Select 

        Selection.Paste 

    Else 

        End if 

Next 

Set copyRng = Nothing 

Exit Sub`

Comment: I think you've got it backwards.  OP wants `CopyFromManySheetsToOneRow`